# How do I install an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I bought a 320gb Seagate FreeAgent Go Hard Drive and I'm not sure how to install it on my system, I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 . It seems to have recognized it, but now I have an icon on my desktop I can't get rid of. (Update: I just 'rebooted' system and now the external hard drive isn't being recognized at all!?)

Comment: You don't need to "install" USB hardware; you just need the kernel driver, which I think Ubuntu comes with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to "install" drivers for most external devices in Ubuntu. However to be able to use them you need to [mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) the device.

When this happened automatically the device is shown as an icon on your desktop, and the USB drive is added to your *Places* menu.

Don't forget to [unmount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) the device before unplugging.

Comment: "There is no need to "install" drivers for external devices in Ubuntu" - this is only true for _most_ devices. For some odd ones you might need a specific module that isn't builtin to the kernel.

Comment: @mathepic: thx for pointing at this :)