# How do I 'mount' my external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have an external hard drive that I can't get to 'mount,' the only place on the system I can find info about the drive is in disk utility, under mount point it says it is unmounted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like a moron, I didn't notice the "mount the volume" button next to the "volume unmounted" notice "Doh!"

Answer (score 0):

Read the answer by Takkat in your previous question [How do i install an internal hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27317/how-do-i-install-an-external-hard-drive)

Comment: If you read the update my system is no longer recognizing the drive after rebooting!

Comment: You really should add updated information as a comment not in the body of the question - good news that you've fixed it, if Takkat's answer solved your problem you should accept it and add a vote too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mount it from the Disk utility, you can simply open places and click on the device and it should mount automatically.